# If I vote down on a question that later will be flagged and deleted, do I return that 1 reputation point that I lose on downvoting?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

If I vote down on an answer that later will be flagged and deleted, do I return that 1 reputation point that I lose on downvoting? I haven't tried that earlier, sorry for a maybe stupid question.

Answer (score 11):

Voting down questions does not cost you reputation, only downvoting answers costs you reputation.

If, however, you downvote an answer and it is deleted, then yes, your reputation is "refunded". This also includes if the question the answer belongs is deleted, as all answers are deleted at the same time.

Of course the reverse is true too and if the answer is undeleted, your "cost" will be re-incurred.

Comment: If you downvote an answer that subsequently gets deleted, you should gain more rep.

Comment: That would just promote people to down vote posts and would be awful for the community, @0-1. Would you suggest that if you upvote a post that is then deleted you should lose reputation too?